# Two divs below one another and towards right

Tags: css

I am trying to place two divs one below another. Both should also be positioned towards right. So I am using margin-left:auto and margin-right:0 . I am unable to find a solution on how to place them below each other as well as position them towards right.

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: There are 20 different ways to achieve this, so let us know how did you start, and we can offer you solutions that match your attempt.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [SO], It's important to share the code that you have attempted. Have a quick read of [ask].  It's difficult to see what the exact problem is and how to help you without a [mcve].

Comment: @javirs I tried using position:absolute and relative. It didnt work .

Comment: I cannot share my code as its confidential to the company

Comment: You don't need to share the actual proprietary code. You should create a minimal example that reproduces the problem that you are experiencing. without that you won't be able to get an appropriate answer, all answers you will get will be of low quality and not really useful to anyone else either.

Comment: How can a little bit of HTML and CSS, which you can just see straight off devtools be confidential? Just show the two divs and their styling, not the whole code. Replace any confidential text with some random text. Or don't even add text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a `container` `div` place both your `divs` inside.

use `display:flex` on the container & change the direction with `flex-direction:column` to make them on top of each other. now use `align-items:flex-end` to push them to the end.

```css
.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width:100vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="box1">
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="divs"></div>
    <div class="divs"></div>
</div>
```

In your css:

```
.divs{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
 }
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
 }
```

By adding display: flex to the parent div with align-items: flex-end